# Create an Angular "core" library and override/customize it in apps

Tags: angular, architecture

I am working on an Angular (8) web application that need to be adapted to each client (organizations), around 20 clients, so I have to maintain 20 applications. In order to avoid code duplication and having a painful bug fix maintenance, I am thinking about create a "core" library with all the code base, and create 20 apps which use and override the core library (services, components, directives, entities, etc.). About 90% of the code is common to all clients, the 10% left can be entitiy modification (add/remove a field, etc.), change the behaviour of a service, a specific homepage, UI component modifications, etc.

There is a lot of documentation about how to create a library but I haven't find anything about overriding/extending a custom angular library. Is it a good idea to do that :

- Create a BaseService in my core library, which call a back-end (Rest API) for example
- In the application, create a MyService which extends the BaseService, duplicate all the methods of the core service, call the parent method if I don't have to make customization. If I have to implement a specific logic, I just have to put it in the MyService.

For example :

```
//------------------------------------//
//- Base service of the CORE library -//
//------------------------------------//
export class BaseProductService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): IProduct[] {
    return this.httpClient.get<IProduct[]>(url);   
  }

  getProduct(id: number): IAgent {
    return this.httpClient.get<IProduct>(url + '/' + id);
  }

  functionA() {

  }

}

//------------------------------------//
//- Service in a client specific app -//
//------------------------------------//
export class ProductService extends BaseProductService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(httpClient);
  }

  getProducts(): IProduct[] {
    // No specific behaviour, call the core
    return super.getProducts();
  }

  getProduct(id: number): IProduct {
    // Specific
    return new IProduct(number);
  }

  functionA() {
    // Specific
    alert('Specific code of Product Service');
  }
}
```

Is it a good solution according to you ? What are the best practices ?

Thank you

Comment: I have a similar architecture in one of my apps. I have few private methods and few protected methods you can have public methods in base so you donot want to duplicate you can type protected so the service must override methods basically oops simulation in JS thats all. I think this looks great

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another question, for the routing, if I define it in the core library, can I inherit and override it in the consuming app ?

Comment: or you can publish your core project as a library and use in any sub project you want. you may need to publish only the necessary files as the core project. In customized project merge these files accordingly and use them as a normal angular project